# Specify multiple files type in interface

Tags: typescript

How can I specify multiple files type in interface?

```
interface App {
    service: Record<ServiceName, Service>
}
```

Where ServiceName must be Cart | Product | User ..etc. And Service must be imported object from *.ts file
My directory structure is kind of

```
- model
- handler
- service
  * Cart.ts
  * Product.ts
  * User.ts
```

Comment: I don't understand, you want to dynamically import your types from your `service/` folder?

Comment: Reason is that App represents dependencies needed for application. Aim is to not every time when new service created change the interface type adding new ones, it's not only for service/ but different modules.

Answer (score 1):

The only option I see to resolve your issue is to use the package `glob` (with types in `@types/glob`). With this you can get your file types and I assume dynamically import your files.

Ths only issue with your solution is that you will have to do code splitting for every service (cart.js, product.js etc...) because when transpilled, it will be looking for these files.